# Jquery plugin not working after display block with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use some divs like tabs with jQuery in my project . Inside the div I want to use another jQuery plugin . I built those div tabs manually with jQuery and the default style for second and more divs are `display: none` with pure css or class name . When I change display of divs to `display: block` the second jQuery plugin inside the div not working .

Only second jQuery plugin can work correctly when I use code blow for hiding divs and don't using pure css or class name :

```
$('div.selector').hide();
```

The problem shows in this case , when html page loading for first time , there is a delay about 1sec to hide divs with jquery . Any suggestion except using loading logo for this case ?

I used bootstrap tabs and the problem still exist too .

How can I use pre-defined class or pure css to `display: none` divs for this case and client click to the button to show div and second jQuery plugin work correctly inside the div ?

```
<div class="tabs-wrapper">
    <div class="tab-container tab1">
        some code here
    </div>
    <div class="tab-container tab2 d-none">
        <div>
            second jquery plugin code here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button id="btn1">Btn1</button>
<button id="btn2">Btn2</button>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('#btn1').click(function () {
        $('.tabs-wrapper .tab1').addClass('d-none');
        $('.tabs-wrapper .tab2').removeClass('d-none');
    });

    $('#btn2').click(function () {
        $('.tabs-wrapper .tab2').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.tabs-wrapper .tab1').addClass('d-none');
    });
});
</script>
```

When I used css class or inline style for hiding divs , the second jQuery plugin not working , the second plugin like same jquery sliders .

Comment: provide js code here..to check what you have done for it

Comment: code added to the question bro

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#btn1').click(function () {
            $('.tabs-wrapper .tab1').addClass('d-none');
            $('.tabs-wrapper .tab2').removeClass('d-none');
        });
    
        $('#btn2').click(function () {
            $('.tabs-wrapper .tab1').removeClass('d-none');
            $('.tabs-wrapper .tab2').addClass('d-none');
        });
```

```css
.d-none
{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-wrapper">
    <div class="tab-container tab1">
        some code here
    </div>
    <div class="tab-container tab2 d-none">
        <div>
            second jquery plugin code here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button id="btn1">Btn1</button>
<button id="btn2">Btn2</button>
```

You can try this way

```
$(function(){
    $('#btn1').click(function () {
        $('.tabs-wrapper .tab1').addClass('d-none');
        $('.tabs-wrapper .tab2').removeClass('d-none');
    });

    $('#btn2').click(function () {
        $('.tabs-wrapper .tab1').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.tabs-wrapper .tab2').addClass('d-none');
    });
});
```

Comment: When I use class name for hiding the divs , second jQuery plugin not working , but I must to use " $('.tab2').hide(); " for solving this problem . Is there a better way to handle this problem in your  Opinion bro ?  @Anonymous

Comment: If i use " $('.tab2').hide(); " , first time page loading has a delay to hiding for example " .tab2 " div , and in this way the delay for hiding div in my problem bro .

Comment: You mean you don't want to have delay time?

Comment: Simply because your javascript code is putting the bottom file (I mean the js file is loaded after css & html are loaded).

Comment: Yes bro , How can I reduce or manage delay time for hiding the div ( Except using pre-loading Logo ) ?

Comment: It depends on how much is your html & css file. You can also put your code in [$( document ).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: I see , the code `$(function(){ });` equal to `$( document ).ready();`

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look @Javid

Answer (score 0):

Please attach an example of the inner code you want it to run. 
But anyway, a code doesn't run only because you hide or display a div. for that you should handle an event fired when your div is displayed. 
Anyway, for properly displaying or hiding the div, you have a bug in yoer code. 
here is 2 possible fixes (one is marked out )

```
<style>
    .d-none
    {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<body>

<div class="tabs-wrapper">
    <div class="tab-container tab1">
        some code here
    </div>
    <div class="tab-container tab2 d-none">
        <div>
            second jquery plugin code here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button id="btn1">Btn1</button>
<button id="btn2">Btn2</button>

<script>
//Option 1
$(function(){
    $('#btn1').click(function () {
        $('.tabs-wrapper .tab1').addClass('d-none');
        $('.tabs-wrapper .tab2').removeClass('d-none');
    });

    $('#btn2').click(function () {
        $('.tabs-wrapper .tab1').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.tabs-wrapper .tab2').addClass('d-none');
    });
});
/*  Option 2
$(function(){
    $('#btn1').click(function () {
        $('.tab1').hide();
        $('.tab2').show();
    });

    $('#btn2').click(function () {
        $('.tab2').hide();
        $('.tab1').show();
    });
});
*/

</script>
```

Comment: If I got the parent selector , problem still exist , but when I use " $('.tab2').hide(); " for example , the second jQuery plugin work correctly . From your experience in programming , Is there a better way Optimize the code ? @Rami Khawaly

Comment: 1. What you mean by you got a parent selector, please expand the code with a parent as you meant so I can run and reproduce the problem.
2. What you mean by optimizing the code ? Shorten it? If yes, so I have some ideas to make it nicer.